# Jinja treats all Flask-Login users as not authenticated

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-login

I am sending a list of users to a template and want to display the ones that are logged in. However, when I loop over them and check `is_authenticated`, it's always false. The following code shows no usernames, although I expect it to show the current user's name.

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {{ user.username }}
    {% else %}
        - 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried using `current_user` but that only shows the current user, not all the list of users.

Comment: are you sure that user class have is_authenticated method/property?

Comment: What is `user`? What is its type? How is it set?

Comment: I altered my database and it works.  
Base.html-code: 
               Active User: {% for active in user %}
      {% if active.logged_in == 1 %}
         {{ active.username }}
      {% endif %}
route.py-code:
        user = user.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first()
        user.logged_in = 1
        db.session.commit()

Everytime a user logs in, user.logged_in = 1 is saved in my databse . The other way around with user.logged_in = 0  whenever a user logs out.  - thx for the help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

`is_authenticated` is true for all users even if they are not logged in. Only the anonymous user is not authenticated. If you want to display only the logged in user, then use `current_user`. If you want to mark the logged in user in a list, then compare each user to `current_user` while iterating.

```
<ul>{% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user.username }}{% if user.username == current_user.username %} (current){% endif %}</li>
{% endfor %}</ul>
```

Your user class will only have the `is_authenticated` property if you subclass `UserMixin` (or if you define it yourself). Jinja interprets unknown variables as false, so if you don't subclass then Jinja will always think `is_authenticated` is false because it doesn't exist.

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    ...
```

---

Knowing the full list of users that are logged in is a much larger problem. The request only knows about the current user, since login is handled with cookies on each user's browser. Your application will need to set up some other way to track who is logged in. For example, you could store the time each user logs in on the model, then consider them logged in if they did within one day.